# Creating a new routing protocol for ns2

Tags: c++, network-protocols, ns2

How can you create new mobile adhoc network routing protocols for ns2? I am still relatively new to ns2, and I already read some answers regarding my question, but I honestly still don't quite get it. I was hoping to find a much easier way of understanding the process of creating a new protocol that can be implemented in ns2.

Answer (score 0):

---

Well, you could start with adding one of the already existing "mobile adhoc network routing protocols"

https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=mobile+adhoc+network+routing+protocols

→ → http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ad_hoc_routing_protocols

OLSR ? ZRP ? And read the patches to know which files are to be added / edited.

---

Please ask. New patches are available for ns-2.35 for various protocols.

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)